# Myths of the Bermuda Triangle and its validity

Tags: myth-identification

The enigma of the Bermuda triangle is a time old tale and it is often even called the Devil's triangle. There are tales of a sea monster living in that area, extraterrestrial actions, etc., happening in that region that cause ships and planes to disappear. Do the tales and myths surrounding the mysterious affects of the Bermuda Triangle have any validity? I have read that there are very erratic waves in that area and strong magnetic effects. But is it just these reasons that have given way to all these tales or is there a deeper scientific answer?

Comment: Leonard Nimoy can tell you everything you need to know about the Bermuda Triangle from his old show ["In Search Of"](https://youtu.be/4XyDNJHJtCE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of the Mythological nature of your question.
The Bermuda Triangle is a modern thing dating from 1945 and lost of 5 airships. They totally and simply vanished. No wreckage. No bodies. Silence. By the way Spielberg used that event in Close Encounters of the Third Kind.
But anyway, put the Bermuda Triangle in the usual basket:

- Area 51
- Nessie
- Crop circles
- Nostradamus/Saint Malachy/Paco Rabanne prophecies
  There is dozen of such hoaxes and the modern Internet  so love hoaxes!

Comment: Well, folktales seem to be on-topic here, and these crazy conspiracy theories and hoaxes tend to shade into that realm.

Comment: Yes well, if this ever gets moved to Skeptics Stack  Exchange I'll upvote it.